# Creating a function that calculate the mean with out using a built in function on python

Tags: python, pandas, function, statistics, mean

Hi I am trying to create a function that will calculate the mean of a column in a dataframe, without using python built in functions.
This is how I did it initially

```
    A       B
0   180.0   70
1   170.0   65
2   190.5   80
3   175.0   75
4   190.0   90
5   190.0   90
6   195.0   95
7   200.0   100
8   205.0   105
9   210.0   110
```

```
n =len(df2["B"]) 
total = sum(df2["B"])
mean=total/n
```

Now I wanted to create a built in function this was my attempt but it is giving me an error. Please assist where I went wrong. (A disclaimer this is a tutorial question).

```
def summary_statistics(df, column_name):
    n =len(df2[column_name])
    total=sum(df2[column_name])
    mean = total/n
    return mean
    
summary_statistics(df2,["B"])
```

Comment: The dataframe you pass into the function is called df, but in the function you use 'df2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
def summary_statistics(df, column_name):
    n =len(df[column_name])
    total=sum(df[column_name])
    mean = total/n
    return mean
    
summary_statistics(df2, "B")
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use pandas functions [`Series.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.size.html) and [`Series.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html), then pass column name without `[]` to function abd change `df2` to `df`:

```
def summary_statistics(df, column_name):
    n = df[column_name].size
    total = df[column_name].sum()
    mean = total/n
    return mean
    
out = summary_statistics(df2,"B")
```

If using length is always same for each column, so is possible use:

```
def summary_statistics(df, column_name):
    n = len(df)
    total = df[column_name].sum()
    mean = total/n
    return mean
```